# Is this function differentiable, if so at which points?

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, piecewise-continuity

Suppose we have the following piecewise defined function for $v,s >0$:
$$
\begin{align}
f(v,s) = 
\begin{cases}
v/s \ &\text{for} \ v < s \\
1 \ &\text{for} \ v \geq s
\end{cases}
\end{align}
$$
And the following function integrating over the previously mentioned function:
$$
F(v) = \int_{\underline{s}}^{\overline{s}} f(v,s) \ ds
$$
Where $\underline{s},\ \overline{s}$ represent some finite bounds to the integral with $\underline{s} < \overline{s}$. While I would say that $f(v,s)$ is not differentiable at the point $v=s$, I somehow can not wrap my head around $F(v)$ and would really appreciate any help.

My questions are basically:

1. Is $F(v)$ differentiable in $v$?
2. If yes, where?
3. If not, why not?

Thank you guys!

Comment: what happnes if $s=0$, $v=-1$?

Comment: Sorry, you can think of $v,s$ being strictly positive. I'm going to edit it.

Comment: Did you try to compute $F$ directly? Since $f$ is given and quite simple, you can compute $F$. Or does $\underline{s}$ and $\overline{s}$ depend on $v$? If not, you have three cases. Either $v\leq\underline{s}$, then $F(u)=\overline{s}-\underline{s}$ or $v\in (\underline{s},\overline{s}]$ then $F(v)=v-\underline{s}+v\ln(\overline{s})-v\ln(v)$ or $v>\overline{s}$ then $F(v)=v(\ln(\overline{s})-\ln(\underline{s}))$.

Comment: Thanks @MundronSchmidt, I think this helps a lot as I could not translate how the piecewise definition of $f(v,s)$ translates into the piecewise character of $F(v)$. Checking for differentiability should be doable now, even for me :).

Answer (score 1):

Have you heard of the [Fundamental Theorem of Calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus)? The integrand is continuous.